# How to remove the excess div background color on top of the h2 tag when applied with border property?

Tags: html, css

I am new at CSS and I came across a problem. I made a div element with an h2 element inside of it. When I colored the two of them, there wasn't any problem at first, however, when I used the border property, I noticed an excess background color from the div element added on top of the h2 element. I tried using the padding-top property and tried to adjust the height of both the h2 and div element, however, it wasn't able to fix the problem. The code snippet for HTML and CSS are located below.

You can preview the output here:

[image: You can preview the output here]

```css
div {
  background-color: rgba(49, 230, 243, 0.904);
  border: 2px black solid;
}

h2 {
  background-color: rgb(17, 88, 77);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit labore suscipit ipsa quis praesentium optio placeat deserunt adipisci, aliquam perferendis cupiditate sit eveniet eos incidunt earum repellat vitae at fuga.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the dark background color that's width is 100%?

Comment: No. What i want to remove is the light color particularly the one top of the h2 element. It just appears when I applied the border property.

Comment: add a `margin-top: 0` to the h2.